# Apache POI percentage format not working

Tags: java, apache-poi, dataformat

I have a module where I have to take double values from html form and then populate them in an excel using Apache POI.

Excel cells are showing percentage.
Module is not working.
please see code

```
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setDataFormat(wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("##.##%"));
    sheet.getRow(4).getCell(3).setCellValue(wifimodel.getMobileSubscriberCountToday());
    sheet.getRow(4).getCell(3).setCellStyle(style);
```

Now wifimodel.getMobileSubscriberCountToday() value is 10.0 and in excel it comes as 1000,%

please help

Comment: Are you aware that `10%` is normally represented mathematically as `0.10` ?

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved with your solution

Answer (score 4):

Promoting a comment to an answer

In maths equivalences, and in computers, percentages are stored as relative to 1 not 100. As [wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage), that's because a percentage is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100. As such, `10%` is not stored as `10`, but instead as `0.10`. That means that to store your value of `10%`, you need to put it in an Apache POI cell formatted as a percentage, with a numeric value of `0.10`.

As you have found, putting in a value of `10` is treated as `10*100 = 1,000 %`, which is 100 times what you had in mind!